# Guidance with programmatic animations

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to run a programatic animation in my app without blocking the runloop. What's a good way to do this?

Is there a way to do something similar to a `CADisplayLink` loop that the `OpenGL` templates do? Can I just set up that same runloop but do view transformations instead of updating a GL View?

**Edit:** I've gotten a display link up and running but I'm not sure how to make it work so that I can execute a block every n seconds? Any tips for working with `CADisplayLink`?

**Edit 2:**
Essentially, I'm trying to cause a view to pulse or transform. I'm not quite sure how to do this. The CADisplayLink fires many times per second, so I'm unsure how to calculate the change per frame.

I've set up a `CADisplayLink` in my view, like so:

```
@interface SomeView
@property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
@end

@implementation SomeView
//...
 - (id)init 
 {
   self = [super init]

   if (self) {

    _displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(update)];      
    [_displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode: runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
   }

   return self;
 }

 - (void)update
 {
   // What can I put here to smoothly resize a view with transforms?
 }
 @end
```

Can someone explain how to do this?